# Numpy array with a subcript of the same array

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to know how this instruction:

```
az[az > 360] -= 360
```

work in python. `az` is a `numpy` array  with the following values:

```
[360.02746582   1.04919434   2.04620361   3.03771973   4.02923584
   5.04547119   6.0369873    7.05322266   8.04473877   9.0335083
  10.02227783  11.04125977  12.04376221  13.05725098  14.04602051
  15.04302979  16.04827881  17.03704834  18.03405762  19.04205322
  20.05004883  21.02508545  22.04681396  23.03833008  24.05181885
  25.0378418   26.04858398  27.04284668  28.03985596  29.03686523
...]
```

It seems to me that is normalizing to less than 360 value the array, but how the subscript works?

Comment: It is subtracting 360 from values which are >360. The `az > 360` returns a boolean array, and it is using advanced indexing to update the values where the boolean array is `True`.

Comment: For practical purposes here, you could also do `az %= 360` (all values modulo 360).

Comment: Thanks you for your insight.

Comment: I'm guessing that these numbers represent longitudes?

Answer (score 0):

In general, `az[az > 360] -= 360` is subtracting 360 from all the values in array `az` that are greater than 360.

Example `az`:

```
[360.02746582   1.04919434   2.04620361   3.03771973]
```

Steps:

- `az > 360` returns a boolean mask of same shape as `az` that is `True` when corresponding value in `az` is greater than 360 and `False` otherwise.
  Example:

  ```
  [ True False False False]
  ```
- `az[az > 360]` selects ALL the values from `az` for which `az>360` boolean mask is `True`, hence ALL the values of `az` that are greater than 360.

  ```
  [360.02746582]
  ```
- Finally, `az[az > 360] -= 360` subtracts 360 from those selected values in step above.

  ```
  [0.02746582 1.04919434 2.04620361 3.03771973]
  ```